# Simple PHP array for storing text?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to learn some basic PHP but am running into some confusion around using arrays.

I have three "pools" of words. 20 words in each pool for a total of 60 words.

I need to store these in separate arrays, and then pull out a random selection from the array on click of a button. So each time the button is clicked, another four will be pulled from my array of 20 entries.

You can see my non-functioning page here: http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/

So the words on the side, when you click the button it'd run through the 20 words in the array and output them in each span, just four each time you click the button.

I looked on the PHP site and found this but I'm confused about which one to use.

Ultimately I would like to add this to a database as in the end if will be 50 words per pool, but for now I want to keep it all in one place while I practice.

```
<?php
$fruits = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);
?>
```

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Here is why: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @larsAnders  None of the content in my website works, it was more there to help illustrate the interface. I'm not asking for help on the code on the site, I'm asking for help on the code posted in the question.

Comment: Well do you  want  to load more words try use mysql + php is more easy

Comment: @user3173819 That doesn't help answer the question about which of the arrays in the code is best for my purpose right now. It's not "more easy" when you're trying to do something a particular way. I don't want to use a database at present.

Comment: I see 12 words on the page, but you have 20 words per group? And are you only wanting to update 4 at a time, or all 12 words?

Comment: The question is phrased quite badly (I barely understand what you're asking). So, if I understand it right, you can use `array_shuffle` to randomize contents in your arrays, then take 4 first elements of each, create JSON of those 12 elements with `json_encode`, and pull this service from your page via AJAX request.

Comment: @larsAnders 20 words per group which I want to store in an array. I only want to output 4 from each pool each time you click the button. I'm just not sure which of the arrays above is best.

Comment: Do you want it to choose the words randomly, but also keep track of which words have been shown to the user?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph yes that sounds right. As I said, I'm learning, so I'm sorry if my explanation doesn't use the right technical terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of arrays:

```
array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key' => 'value',
    'key' => 'value',
)
```

and

```
array(
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
);
```

the latter is the same as:

```
array(
    0 => 'value',
    1 => 'value',
    2 => 'value',
    3 => 'value',
);
```

it's really how you want to use them...

if you loop through them with

```
foreach($array as $value) {

}
```

or

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

}
```

and there is no need for named keys, just use the second array.

edit:

```
$array = array(
    'one' => array ('qwe1rty1','qwe1rty2','qwe1rty3'),
    'two' => array ('qwe2rty1','qwe2rty2','qwe2rty3'),
    'three' => array ('qwe3rty1','qwe3rty2','qwe3ert3'),
);

$array['one'][2] === 'qwe1rty3' (index starts at 0)
$array['three'][0] === 'qwe3rty1'

foreach($array['one'] as $key => $value) {
     echo $key .' : ' $value;
}
```

gives

```
0 : qwe1rty1
1 : qwe1rty2
2 : qwe1rty3
```

Comment: What would you recommend using for this solution? I don't think a key is required in this case? But I don't understand how I can have three different arrays (word pool 1, word pool 2, word pool 3).

Comment: I think you need an array of arrays like `$arr = array(array("a", "b", "c", ...), array("x", "y", "z", ...), array(1, 2, 3, ...))`, then iterate over it with double `foreach`: `foreach ($arr as $row) { foreach ($row as $cell) { ... } }`.

Comment: Do you have a good example of a page which explains this in detail? I am struggling to understand any PHP pages on arrays. I have no idea what a lot of those words mean. I just can't seem to find any basic explanations of how to store data like this.

Comment: @Francesca if you need the absolute basics, try [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_arrays.asp)

Comment: I already looked, and could not find the explanation of which is best to use and how to differentiate three different arrays by different names.

Comment: array(
'one' => array ('name','name','name'),

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that is similar to what you're describing:

```
$words = array("tasty", "wretched", "simple", "gnarly", "fruitful", "cleeeever");

echo $words[1]; //prints wretched

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {//prints array in original order
    echo $words[$i].'<br/>';
}

shuffle($words);

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {//prints shuffled array
    echo $words[$i].'<br/>';
}
```